# Problems with addSiteAccount1

Tags: json, yodlee

I'm following the Quick Start Guide, as I've just received my credentials. I went through the coblogin and user (consumer) creation successfully. For test purposes, I was able to search and list sites and infos.

When I try to invoke addSiteAccount1 using the user session token for the consumer that I create, I get an HTTP 200 response and no apparent error, no exceptions or messages. The JSON response is basically the same as the one listed in the API documentation page, however there's no ID I can use to list transactions. I'm using a real login/password account information on Chase (site ID 643).

By the way, if I use random strings for credentialFields[0].value (username) and credentialFields[1].value (password), I get the same JSON response.

Please help me clarify what is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addSiteAccount1 API will give you a response which should contain "siteAccountId" field this is the identifier for that particular user's Chase bank site.
This siteAccountId will have itemIDs which resembles different 'container'(in Yodlee terminology) like, all saving and checking accounts comes under bank container,while credit card comes under credit's container similarly loan and mortgages are other containers.

Now even under a specific container you might have multiple accounts for e.g., Chase Bank container you might have 1 saving's account and 1 checking account, for each there will be an itemAccountId available. This uniquely identifies that specific account and you can pass this itemAccountId (which you can get from getItemSummariesForSite API) in executeUserSearchRequest API to get the transactions belongs to this specific account.

For further help [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account) is the link for the API flow which will give you an idea about how and when to use different APIs.

Comment: the problem arises if I provide a wrong user/password combination, I will get the siteAccountId anyway. It won't be until I check later if the entry was successful, or not. As far as the items and other terminology, I got it, I was able to retrieve 90 days worth of transactions from a Checkings Account, for example.

Comment: To provide you more info- once you call addSiteAccount1 API(even with wrong credentials) it will provide you a response having siteAccountId and status whether it triggered a refresh for that item or not. Yodlee requires to pass these credentials to check if it is correct or not and then provide you the respective response, which you can get using getSiteRefreshInfo. Hope this helps in understanding.

Comment: I would like to follow-up on this question. All banks I've tried so far have skipped the MFA step as defined in the API flow:

https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account

After invoking addSiteAccount1, I get the REFRESH_TRIGGERED status, as well as MFA Type: Security Question. The reality is though that the synchronization process started without any MFA interaction.

My questions are: is it because there's some sort of pre-authorization in the connection with certain Banks? Chase, Ameritrade?

Second concern: I could not test the MFA flow.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it working, but maybe some documentation clarification is needed. Provided that all mandatory parameters in the addSiteAccount1 are present and contain no errors, the method call will be successful for a given consumer.

I then visited the **`getAllSiteAccounts`** method, which would show me all account aggregation for that user/consumer. I was able to see all accounts added, some had a message like "REFRESH_COMPLETE" and others would have "AUTH_FAILED". It seems that once one adds an account, the Yodlee robots will try to login and then synchronize the data for a given account. Makes sense?

I was only able to verify if the bank credentials were OK by calling another method.